# Laravel 4 : model assocation (belongsTo)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model-associations

I have a very simple tables association with laravel 4 :

```
foods table
  id
  name
  food_category_id

food_categories table
  id
  name
```

Here are my two models:

```
//models/Food.php         
class Food extends Eloquent {
    public function food_category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('FoodCategory');
    }
}


//models/FoodCategory.php
class FoodCategory extends Eloquent {

}
```

When trying to extract category information form the Food model :

in controller:

```
class FoodController extends \BaseController {
    public function index()
    {
        $foods = Food::all();
        return View::make('admin/food/index',compact('foods'));
    }
}
```

In view:

```
@foreach($foods as $food)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $food->id }} </td>
            <td>{{ $food->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $food->description}}</td>
            <td>{{ $food->price}}</td>
            <td>{{ $food->food_category->name }}</td>        
        </tr>
@endforeach
```

I get the below error message :

**Trying to get property of non-object (View:
/Library/WebServer/Documents/xxx/test/app/views/admin/food/index.blade.php)**

Based on the [dynamic properties](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#dynamic-properties), data should be available from ->food>category

- I've followed the naming convention for laravel.
- Data exists in the database

[image: http://s4.postimg.org/eog8nuf7x/Screen_Shot_2014_05_08_at_19_58_17.png]

Debugging with dd(DB::getQueryLog()) :

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(3) { ["query"]=> string(44) "select * from `users` where `id` = ? limit 1" ["bindings"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(6) } ["time"]=> float(0.79) } [1]=> array(3) { ["query"]=> string(21) "select * from `foods`" ["bindings"]=> array(0) { } ["time"]=> float(0.32) } }
```

======= UPDADED

When adding eager loading :

```
$foods = Food::with('food_category')->get();
```

I got  :

```
array(3) { [0]=> array(3) { ["query"]=> string(44) "select * from `users` where `id` = ? limit 1" ["bindings"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(6) } ["time"]=> float(0.52) } [1]=> array(3) { ["query"]=> string(21) "select * from `foods`" ["bindings"]=> array(0) { } ["time"]=> float(0.42) } [2]=> array(3) { ["query"]=> string(67) "select * from `food_categories` where `food_categories`.`id` in (?)" ["bindings"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } ["time"]=> float(3.23) } }
```

Comment: Are you calling that inside a view?

Comment: yes, i am using a foreach loop for all elements @foreach($foods as $food) and call it with {{ $food->food_category->name }}

Comment: So `$food` is just `Food::find()`, right? Could you post the actual code that's giving you the error? How you call it in the controller and how/what you pass to the view

Comment: Your relation is ok. It seems that you don't have related `FoodCategory` for one or some of the `Food` models. Also use eager loading like suggested to avoid N+1 issue, but that's not the case here. You can check that by adding `is_null($food->food_category)` where you call category name

Comment: Eager loading `with` method takes as a parameter name of the relation so `food_category` not model name. And you changed the relation `food_category` to `hasOne` ? It's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with eager loading:

```
$foods = Food::with('FoodCategory')->get();
```

Comment: Thank you. Give me few minutes to try with eager loading !

Comment: Eager loading exists to alleviate the N + 1 query problem !

Comment: As Razor said, eager is for avoiding multiple loops, but that is not the case here.

Comment: cannot explain why but with eager loading, it works ! thank you

Comment: But only because your relations are now set correct, right? Because that was the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your relations are inverted. You are asking for `food_category` through `food`. So `food` has a `food_category` and `food_category` belongs to `food` if this should be `hasOne` or `hasMany` I can't see from your example.

Database

```
foods table
  id
  name

food_categories table
  id
  name
  food_id
```

models/Food.php

```
class Food extends Eloquent {
    public function food_category()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('FoodCategory');
    }
}
```

models/FoodCategory.php

```
class FoodCategory extends Eloquent {

}
```

Comment: Thank you. No, my food objects have a food_category_id . example : Category=>meat food=>beef

Comment: That is what I wrote right? If it doesn't work, could you then post more clearly what you want. Because this should be easy to do! ;)

Comment: I ve added a capture of my db.

Answer (score -1):

I think to resolve this question, you have two choice:

**Fisrt:**

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('FoodCategory');
}
```

Then do `{{ $food->category->name }}` which is more elegant

**Second:**   just add 'id'

```
public function food_category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('FoodCategory','food_category_id');
}
```

Comment: Your 2nd option is wrong, it should be foreign key as 2nd param so `food_category_id` which might be omitted here

Comment: Thank you. Both of your solutions end with the same error

Comment: @johann add `dd(DB::getQueryLog());` before returning the view, and add eagerLoading relation to see both queries, let us know the result

Comment: I've added the getQueryLog (without the eagerLoading). (question updaded) thank you

Comment: I've tried with the eager loading and a different error appears (question updaded). Thank you for your help

Comment: I've updaded with the with method